# Parsing Json into State

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to parse the returned JSON in the code below, more specifically I am trying to add the res.name to the components state.

You can see I have got as far as **this.setState({results:res})**, this add the entire response object to the component state but I am having difficulty 'drilling down' to the name values. I tried to to use console.log(res.results) but it comes back as undefined, could some lend a helping hand to shed some light on this problem..

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      results: []
    }
  }

  apiRequest() {
    request('http://localhost:3000/api', function (error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body))
          console.log(res.results) // Should this not work?
          this.setState({results:res})
      }
    }.bind(this))
  }
```

**Returned 'res' Json**

```
{
    "count":87,
    "next":"http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2",
    "previous":null,
    "results":[
        {"name":"Luke Skywalker"},
        {"name":"Han Solo"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: isn't response.body already a json?

Comment: So need need for the stringify right?

Comment: there is no need for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response should already be a JSON object. So, calling
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))`

will take you back to square one. You're serializing and deserializing the same object.

You should be able to do:

`console.log(JSON.stringify(response));`

Which will output the entire object to your console so you can see everything.

Then you can just store the object directly in the state, by calling:

`this.setState({results:response.body})`

Comment: Many thanks! I did think I should be using response but did not seem to be getting any results, must have made a mistake somewhere as this works fine now

Comment: @James `JSON.stringify(response.body)` was converting a string (representing JSON) to a JSON string (containing escaped JSON, ie you double-encoded the JSON). So `JSON.parse()` was only returning you to the original JSON string, not a decoded object. `JSON.parse(response.body)` gives you the decoded object.